# Cannot access local network after switching desktop environment to gnome 3

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, 17.04, lan

I have internet access but cannot access my local network after upgrading to ubuntu 17.04 and switching from unity to gnome 3. The network is not down as I have asked others and they can access it.

```
ssh local_server
ssh: Could not resolve hostname local_server: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And when accessing ont the web this is the error thrown:

```
This site can’t be reached

local_server’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: @pomsky I tried both wired & wifi neither works

Comment: I tried ssh bit also we have our own internal websites that can only be accessed inside the network. So tried both through ssh and web.

Comment: hmm... I think you better add some more info to your question, like what you have tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: @pomsky updates to original question